# Link 2 wp_options

Tags: wordpress

I create a configuration plugin to manage site settings that are therefore wp_options.

I would like to be able to choose one or more projects from a list (displayed as checkboxes). 
Those that are selected are then saved in the wp_options, then I would like to associate parameters to these projects, such as a URL.

That's when I have problems...

When I update the selected projects, the associated parameters such as URLs do not update themselves

Here are samples of my code:

```
<?php
    //wp_options of projects
    public function page_config_init_list_projects(){ 
        add_settings_section(
            'projet-section',
            'Choix des projets',
            array( $this, 'print_projets_section_info' ),
            'configuration-projet' // Page
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'name', 
            'Liste des projets', 
            array( $this, 'project_chosen_callback' ),
            'configuration-projet', // Page
            'projet-section' // Section
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'url',
            'URL',
            array( $this, 'url_callback' ),
            'configuration-projet', // Page
            'projet-section' // Section
            );

        register_setting(
            'config-projets', // Option group
            'projets' // Option name
        );
    }

    //saving the projects chosen
    public function project_chosen_callback(){        
        $items = array("project 1", "project 2", "project 3";

        foreach ( $items as $id => $item) {                
            $names_projects = array();
            foreach ($this->projetOptions as $projet){
                array_push($names_projects, $projet['name']);
            }

            if ( in_array($item , $names_projects) )  {
                $checked = 'checked="checked"';
            } else $checked = null;              

            echo '<input type="checkbox" id="name" name="projets[][name]" value="'. $item .'"'. $checked.'/> '. $item .'</p>';
        }
    }

    // parameter URL linked to a project chosen... here are the problems//
    public function url_callback(){                

        foreach ($this->projetOptions as $id=>$projet){
            echo $projet['name'] . ' : ';

            printf(
                '<input type="text" id="url" name="projets['.$id.'][url]" value="%s" /><br>',
                isset( $projet['url'] ) ? esc_attr( $projet['url']) : ''
            );
        }
    }
```

For the moment I'm trying to make the `projects` option respond to a structure of this type:

```
array(2) { 
   [0]=> array(2) { 
                     ["name"]=> string(8) "project 1" 
                     ["url"]=> string(4) "test"
                   } 
   [1]=> array(1) { 
                      ["name"]=> string(8) "project 2"
                   } 
}
```

When I choose a project and associate it with a URL, it works well. however, when I deselect the project, it deletes itself from wp_options but the url remains.
Also, URLs are associated with IDs and not with projects, so when the list of selected projects changes, then the URLs shift...

Well I really don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

Okk so I found a solution if anyone encounters the same troubles. Not pretty I admit but if the projects' list does not change, it's okay. If anyone have better ideas, do not hesitate to share them!

I associate the chosen project with its index in the wp_options table, so I can retrieve the url associated with this index.

```
   public function project_chosen_callback(){        
        $items = array("project 1", "project 2", "project 3");

        foreach ( $items as $id => $item) {

            if ( in_array($item , $this->projetOptions['name']) )  {
                $checked = 'checked="checked"';
            } else $checked = null;

            echo '<input type="checkbox" id="name" name="projets[name]['.$id.']" value="'. $item .'"'. $checked.'/> '. $item .'</p>';

        }
    }

    public function url_callback(){                
        foreach ( $this->projetOptions['name'] as $id => $name) {
            echo $name.' :<br>';

            printf(
                '<input type="text" id="url" name="projets[url]['.$id.']" value="%s" /><br><br>',
                isset( $this->projetOptions['url'][$id] ) ? esc_attr( $this->projetOptions['url'][$id]) : ''
                );
        }
    }
```